# Can I use Resource Strings in a JsonProperty Attribute in C#?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, attributes, json.net

I'm connecting to an API that is likely to be modified significantly in the coming months, and want to store the correlating API tags in a resource to ensure that they can be easily updated when changes occur.

When I try to use these resource strings in the JsonProperty (through Newtonsoft) attribute, however, I run into the following error:

```
An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type
```

I have tried creating a custom attribute to solve the issue, but the JsonProperty itself is sealed and is non-inheritable.

Is there a reasonable way for me to approach this?  Am I just missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JsonPropertyAttribute` controls how your classes will be serialized to JSON and back. If you have the actual json property names defined in resource files, then the way that your class will be serialized will change as those resource files are updated, or even if your application simply switches to a different locale. This is generally not a good idea.

However, if your program is changing so frequently that you want to be able to modify the serialization of your classes without recompiling, or if you want to have multiple ways of serializing your classes, I believe you'll have to write your own `IContractResolver`.

Here's an example:

```
public class ResourceNameContractResolver : 
    CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties CreatePropertiesInternal(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var list = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization)
        foreach (JsonProperty p in list)
        {
            p.PropertyName = this.GetRealNameFromResourceFile(p.PropertyName);
        }

        return list;
    }

    private string GetRealNameFromResourceFile(string originalPropertyName)
    {
        // Look up name from resource file
    }
}
```

And to use this class

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
     ContractResolver = new ResourceNameContractResolver()
};
JsonTextWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(...);
JsonSerializer serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(settings);
serializer.Serialize(writer, myData);
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a big performance hit for the contract resolution approach?

Comment: @Maixy I can't imagine that the performance impact would be very big. The biggest hit would come from looking up the property names from the res file every time, although that could be sped up by reading the entire res file into memory on the first attempt.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much for your input and quick response! It seems like the best approach for this situation is for me to just hard code the strings as const within a class and expect to update / recompile them on each API change.